# submit form on page within an iframe?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, iframe

I have a .net 3.5 page which has a form control (form1) and with that form is an iframe which contains a page which contains a form (form_tester).  What I am trying to do is submit form1 and at the same time submit form_tester that is within the iframe, how do you do that?  I know I can submit the form via javascript but I am just wondering if there is a standard way, or a better way of doing it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it in the end by adding a button to the page (form) the was encapsulated within the iframe.  Then I added an onclientclick event to the submit button.  I then added some javascipt which clicks the button on the encapsulated page and hence it get's submitted.  The hardest part was working out how to access the elements on the encapsulated form.

```
window.frames["frame1"].document.forms['hidden_form']["submit_btn"].click();
```

but it does work.

Comment: window.frames["frame1"].document.forms['hidden_form'].submit(); would do it :)

Comment: Ah yes, but by calling the submit button click I get the function I wanted...  But thanks.